"Oauth error: redirect_uri is not whitelisted" due to a non-breaking space
My app is not authenticating due to a non-breaking space in the redirect_uri. I'm not sure what's causing this.
Here's the URL :
https://admin.shopify.com/store/e76aa7/oauth/authorize?client_id=27277406468b379ki9679392dce3ae6b&sc...
Notice that the redirect_uri in the above URL after the domain has %C2%A0 which results in a non-breaking space.
Due to this space URL becomes "https://shop.popseekl.com /api/auth/callback" which results in a different URL than the one mentioned on the Shopify partners dashboard in the allowed URL. I'm unable to figure out where is this coming from.
I have checked the HOST URL and authCallback path. None of them have any extra space. And the Allowed urls on partner dashboard are correct as well.
